# Accessing last Index through substring and also with charAt but getting error in charAt()

Tags: java, indexing, substring

For example I have one **String="something"** now if I will **access the last index(str.length())** of this string it will **give "String index out of range: -1".**
But If I **access this through Substring it does not give any error .**

**String str="something" str.charAt(9); Run time Error ||
Str.substring(9); No error and it will not print anything.**

Please Help

Comment: The index will start from 0. If you want to access the last character you have to call charAt with length -1 => `String str="something"; str.charAt(str.length() -1)`

Comment: Well, read the documentation of both methods. This behavior is mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) documentation mentions (emphasis mine) it clearly

> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or **larger than the length of this `String` object**.

Answer (score 0):

Index will start from 0 and ends at `length-1`.

In order to access the last character, you have to call the charAt function with length-1.

```
String str = "something";
str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

this will give `g` as result.